# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV"

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

i have set the OpenCV_DIR in CMakeLists.txt and ~/.bashrc
but my computer still can not correct path of my opencv

```
By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

[image: shell]
[image: cmake]
[image: bashrc]

Comment: Does the folder you've specified contain `OpenCVConfig.cmake`? Have you started a new shell to make the changes to bashrc take effect?

Comment: Do NOT use images for show the text like a code or an error message. Instead, add that text into the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: Variable `OpenCV_DIR` should contain a (single) **directory**, not a *list* of directories like `PATH` variable. So, `OpenCV_DIR` variable shouldn't contain colon character (`;`) unless the path itself contains that character.